# How to solve de Linear Differential Equation $\dot{x} = Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with real entries, how can I solve the differential equation

$$\dot{x} = Ax.$$

I know that the solution is $x = x_0e^{At}$, but I don't know how to compute that. Sorry if it is duplicated, but I can't found it anywhere.

Comment: do you know how to solve a first order, linear differential equation?? The fact that $A$ is a matrix doesn't affect the answer here. If not your question is definitely a repeat, as this has been answered many times elsewhere

Comment: So is your real question how to compute $e^{At}$, or how to determine that $e^{At} x_0$ solves $\dot x=Ax$?

Comment: How to determine that $e^{At}x_0 solves. I remember that my teacher use eigenvalues to solve it.